# How to save checkmark on current language in Flutter with Easy localization?

Tags: flutter, listview, localization, sharedpreferences

I have a listView.builder inside my Language screen, and i want to save preferences when the language is selected, a checkmark will appear next to.
Language localization work perfectly and also the listView with a radio button checkmark. but when i close the page and come back, the checkmark go back to default language even the current language is still the what user choose.

So, should i load the current language everytime the Language screen is open or should I use Shared preferences to store the checkmark position?

[image]

Comment: Yes you should use `shared_preferences` to save the selected language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use two options:

1. Save it in Shared preferences.
2. Save it in your database.
   This option is very good in the situation when you have a mobile app and web.
   Because it saves profile parameters globally.

Another option that I like is to simply use system locale parameters.
If a user has English language on his phone my application is the same.
But this option is not for web only for mobile applications.